# Merging a set of characters if the next row of characters has the same set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Let's say I have the following string.

```
&eThe quick brown fox &djumps over the &dlazy &adog.
```

Each set of color codes `&letter`, e.g `&e` will change the color of the following text until another color code appears. It's redundant to have two of the same codes follow after each other because it's both the same color.

```
&djumps over the &dlazy
```

I'm trying to merge any duplicate color code that matches the color code before it, so the above string would change into the following:

```
&eThe quick brown fox &djumps over the lazy &adog.
```

However I'm not sure how this is done. Can anyone help?

Comment: if this is a custom thing & is a bad choice for use with html (is &ellipsis an ellipsis or a red llipsis)

Comment: @Alex K., That's why there needs to be an escape mechanism (e.g. `&&` could mean `&`), but none was specified :(

Comment: Sorry, but this is an web addon that is apart of a game that lets players change their colors depending on the color code. I'm not sure of any escape mechanism. Game is Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `String.replace` in combination with callback and an outer variable storing the previous color:

```js
let str = '&eThe quick brown fox &djumps over the &dlazy &adog.';

let last = '';
let result = str.replace(/&([a-z])/g, (match, color) => 
  color !== last ? (last = color, match) : ''
);

console.log(result); // &eThe quick brown fox &djumps over the lazy &adog.
```

Answer (score 0):

*Your markup language needs an mechanism for the situations where the text includes a `&` followed by a letter (e.g. `D&D`, `&lt;`). The exact solution will depend on your escape mechanism. I have provided code that works if your markup language has no escape mechanism (BAD!), and I've also provided code that works if your markup language's escape mechanism consists of doubling the `&` (the most obvious mechanism).*

---

```js
// If you don't have an escape mechanism.

let text = '&eThe quick brown fox &djumps over the &dlazy &adog.';

let prev;
let result = text.replace(
   /&([a-zA-Z])/g,
   match => match === prev ? '' : ( prev = match ),
);

console.log(result);
```

or

```js
// If && is an escaped &, and escaping is optional where unambiguous.

let text = '&eThe quick brown fox &djumps over the &dlazy &adog.';

let prev;
let result = text.replace(
   /&(.)/g,
   function (match) {
      return match.replace(
         /^&([a-zA-Z])/,
         match => match === prev ? '' : ( prev = match ),
      );
   },
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The question is (now) tagged javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @cmbuckley, Oops! Converted.